# Bevel isnt making a edge

Tags: bevel

so its my 2nd day of using blender and im following a tutorial where i need to bevel a edge to make a infinity drop as background. now  when i hit ctrl b bevel is showing up but its not making a edge at all. scale is applied too before trying to add the bevel but its still not making the curve its supposed to do. idk if i need to turn some kind of setting on to make it work but its driving me crazy rn. im using latest blender 4.0.1

Comment: Hello, maybe you need to select all and press M > Merge by Distance, if it doesn't work please show some screenshots or even share your file.

Comment: tysm u just fixed it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disconnected faces, to connect them back select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.